# Send new SMS from SMS callback function

Tags: developer, civisms

I need to automatically send MT SMS message as a response to forwarded MO SMS message.
For that purpose, I created a new `send_mt()` function, but I cannot access Provider object to pick up parameters like provider URL for sending, username/password, etc.
When I do var_dump, it shows that `_providerInfo` member is an empty array.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4):

To send a auto-reply for an incoming SMS you can use [Auto-reply twilio](https://civicrm.org/extensions/auto-reply-twilio-sms) extension. You can modify the extension to support for your provider as this extension supports for only Twilio.

HTH
Pradeep